# Как правильно называть жителей населенного пункта Мурино?

Tags: словообразование

Живем в Мурино, не знаем как нам себя называть.
**Мурчане, муричане, муринцы** или как-то иначе?
Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Вот что нашлось в Википедии:

> [Названия жителей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)
>   В русском языке нет чёткого правила образования названия жителей, однако есть закономерности. Для названий, заканчивающихся на... -ино  используется суффикс -ц- (**ильинцы** — от Ильино).

Нашлось и **Мурино с [муринцами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE_(%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)).**

Жители Пушкино — [пушкинцы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE). Жители Вагино — [вагинцы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE_(%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)).

Comment: Все хорошо! Только ведь **Ров-но**, как мне кажется, под закономерность на -ино не вписывается.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова И то правда, уберу его совсем.

Comment: *>> Жители Пушкино — пушкинцы.* А жители города Пушкина?

Comment: @Niemand, проверил в Русские названия жителей. (Городецкая, Левашов). Там пушкинцы.

Comment: Ну вот: и тут пушкинцы, и там пушкинцы. Поэтому и не стоит создавать этнохоронимы для жителей малых населенных пунктов.

Answer (score 3):

Да как нравится - и муринцы, и муринчане пойдёт для разговорного и стиля и СМИ.

Мурчане,муричане, по-моему, не совсем верно, производящая основа усечена.  Если сказать муриновцы или муриновчане, то указание на Муриново или Муринов.

**Мурино - мурин/цы, мурин/чане**. Только мне всё равно больше по душе **жители посёлка Мурино.**

Answer (score 2):

Не для каждого же населенного пункта можно подобрать подходящий этнохороним. Если он не сложился естественным образом, то что ж... Называйте себя **жителями Мурино**.

Comment: Приношу извинения ― я ошиблась!

Comment: @Aer, если есть возможность, отмените, пожалуйста, мой "минусовый" голос ― даже и не знаю, как ТАК получилось!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова вы можете сами отозвать отрицательный голос, предварительно отредактировав ответ.

Comment: Никогда ещё такой ситуации не было. Только менять-то вроде нечего... Сейчас попробую. P. S. Спасибо, все получилось. Буду знать.